# Android Google Play with Unity Basic?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

Is it possible to send my game made with Unity Basic to Google Play without any charge from Unity (I know there is charge from Google Play)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will be free(you dont have to pay Unity), but there will be a 'Powered by Unity' Splash screen when the app starts in the free version on Unity.